# Monster kills +X experience

Tags: diablo-iii

Doing solo, this is fairly straightforward. With the `monster kills +X experience` property, this will add X experience points per monster killed.

How does this work in multi play however? Do I have to kill the monsters myself, or is "monster kill" meant to be global (i.e. does it give me the experience bonus if someone else lands the killing blow)?

Comment: I believe you need to land the killing blow, although you may only need to land a hit.  It probably uses the same logic that's used for calculating monster kill streaks.

Answer (score 1):

It works in multiplayer exactly the same way it works in single player.  If you are within the "screen and a half" range for getting xp, it works as if you had killed the monster yourself.

I played through all of normal difficulty in a party of 3, and the person who had the most +xp per kill was always the one who leveled first.  Most of the time it was me, and I wasn't getting most of the killing blows based on the number of monster streaks that the other two were reporting.